# R shinyjs disable function not working in module that takes input from another module

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, shinymodules

Below code is a minimum example of what I'm building in a larger app and I can't figure out why the `textInput` in `output_module.R` is not disabled. Would be very grateful if anyone can help!

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    useShinyjs(),

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Demo"),

    # Sidebar 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            input_module_ui("input")
        ),

        mainPanel(
            output_module_ui("output")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    callModule(input_module_server, "input")
    res <- callModule(input_module_server, "input")
    
    callModule(output_module_server, "output", res)
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**input_module.R**

```
#Define ui
input_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    textInput(
      inputId = ns("input"),
      label = "Input:",
      value = "A"
      )
    )
}

#Define server logic 
input_module_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #List of things to return for use in other modules
  return(input)
  
}
```

**output_module.R**

```
#Define ui
output_module_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
        textInput(inputId = ns("output"),
                     label = "Output:", 
                     value = ""
                  )
      )
}

#Define server logic 
output_module_server <-
  function(input,
           output,
           session,
           module_input) {

    observe({
      
      output <- module_input$input
      updateTextInput(session, "output", value = output)
      disable(id = session$ns("output"))
      
    })
  }
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  I enter "M" in the input and "M" is displayed in the output.  Is this not the xpected behaviour?

Comment: The problem is that the output should not be editable, but it is. This should be handled by the disable function and I don’t know why it isn’t working.

Comment: Ah.  I didn't pay attention.  Apologies. It seems that `shinyjs::disable` honours the module namespace.  So `disable(id="output")` gives you what you want.  I would have made the same assumption as you.

Comment: That works, thank you very much @Limey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved thanks to @Limey. Here is the correct code for the module that was edited.

**output_module.R**

```
#Define ui
output_module_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
        textInput(inputId = ns("output"),
                     label = "Output:", 
                     value = ""
                  )
      )
}

#Define server logic 
output_module_server <-
  function(input,
           output,
           session,
           module_input) {

    observe({
      
      output <- module_input$input
      updateTextInput(session, "output", value = output)
      disable(id = "output") #This line was edited to resolve the issue.
      
    })
  }
```